# Solving $ \frac {27 ^ {(2x+1)} } { 3 ^ {(x+1){5}}} = \frac{1}{3} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, exponentiation

I am trying to find the value of $x$ in the following problem, I have to solve it without logarithm.

Problem :
$$
\frac {27 ^ {(2x+1)} } { 3 ^ {(x+1){5}}} = \frac{1}{3}
$$

EDIT:
My work so far:

$$
\dfrac {3^{3(2x+1)} } { 3 ^ {(x+1)5}} = 3^{-1}
$$

I know the formula $b^{u} = b^{v} \Longleftrightarrow u = v$, but I am not able to use it with this problem.

Thanks for help !

Comment: Hint: $27=3^3$.

Comment: $$ \frac{3^{3(2x+1)}}{3^{5(x+1)}}=3^{-1}$$

Comment: Additionally, $\frac{3^a}{3^b}=3^{a-b}$ and $\frac1{3^a}=3^{-a}$...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's combine all the hints (from above comments) to write:

$\dfrac{27^{(2x + 1)}}{3^{5(x + 1)}} = \dfrac{(3^3)^{(2x + 1)}}{3^{(5x + 5)}} = \dfrac{3^{3(2x + 1)}}{3^{(5x + 5)}} = \dfrac{3^{(6x + 3)}}{3^{(5x + 5)}} = 3^{(6x + 3) -(5x + 5)} = 3^{-1}$

Comment: David gives us the first equality, pedja gives us the second, and J.M. gives us the final two. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Is it $$ 6x+3-5x-5 = -1, x = 1 $$ ?

Comment: Come on, now! You have to *distribute that negative/minus!!* So it would be $6x + 3 - 5x -5 = -1$ ...

Comment: sorry! I've just edited it :)

Comment: There you go! And you can always check your solution by plugging $x = 1$ into the original equation. And welcome to math.stackexchange!

Answer (score 0):

Taking logarithm with base $3$ of both sides can be a neater way of solution:
$$\frac {27 ^ {(2x+1)} } { 3 ^ {(x+1){5}}} = \frac{1}{3}$$
$$\small\log_3(27 ^ {2x+1})-\log_3(3 ^ {5x+5}) = \log_3(1)-\log_3(3)
$$
$$(2x+1)\log_3(27)-(5x+5)\log_3(3) = 0-1
$$
$$(6x+3)-(5x+5)=-1$$
$$x=1$$